# Unity macOs build failed to access the camera

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

I am in the process of developing a Unity game that requires access to the camera. The game functions correctly within the Unity Editor.

However, once I build the game as a MacOS app  (standalone app), the authorization request for camera access does not appear.

I am currently seeking a solution to this issue and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Unity 2021.3.13f1 with macOS Monterey

I already checked the following:

1. Build Setting -> Player settings -> Camera Usage Description = "Camera"
2. Mac system preference -> Safe and Security -> Camera: The game app not shown here

Comment: This is an XCode problem, not Unity, of course you can write some postprocess codes to automatically add the capacity to the XCode project when exporting the project. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_device_camera?language=objc

Comment: This not an IOS app. I building the unity project into a standalone app for macOs. Also I included the NSCameraUsageDescription key in my app’s Info.plist file.

Comment: I didn't mention iOS anywhere, the link is also for macOS.

Comment: I am bit confused on using Xcode for the unity build. Based on the link I need to open that build on Xcode and first enable the App Sandbox to add the camera entitlement. But I can't open that application from Xcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the build settings you can choose "Create Xcode Project", then you can do the rest works in Xcode.

Comment: Hi @shingo,  I have the same issue with windows. Couldn't grant permission to access the camera

Comment: @shingo I created the Xcode project , by choosing "Create Xcode Project from the build settings. But I can't open that project from Xcode. Xcode stops responding when ever I try to open that project.

Comment: @Intern That cannot be the same because there is no Xcode on Windows. You can ask a new question.

Comment: @Hjk Sorry I have no idea about the issue of Xcode stopping responding.

Comment: I solved this issue. It was not related to granting access via Xcode. Issue was in unity. Thanks